# Node reply to tweet does not actually reply

Tags: node.js, twitter, bots

I'm using the `Twit` Node library to reply to tweets in a stream and while it's working perfectly the tweeted reply does not show up as a reply on the timeline, instead, it appears as a standalone tweet, not linked to a prior conversation.

Here's my code:

```
function tweetEvent(eventMsg) {
    var replyto = eventMsg.in_reply_to_screen_name;
    var text = eventMsg.text;
    var from = eventMsg.user.screen_name;

    console.log(replyto + ' ' + from);

    if( (text.indexOf('myhandle') >= 0) || (from != 'myhandle')) {
        var reply = replies[Math.floor(Math.random() * replies.length)];
        var newtweet = '@' + from + ' ' + reply;
        tweetIt(newtweet);
    }
}

function tweetIt(txt) {

    var tweet = {
      status: txt
    }

    T.post('statuses/update', tweet, tweeted);

    function tweeted(err, data, response) {
      if (err) {
        console.log("Something went wrong!");
      } else {
        console.log("It worked!");
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for the reply to show up in the timeline using the Twitter API, you need the following:

```
// the status update or tweet ID in which we will reply
var nameID  = eventMsg.id_str;
```

Also needed is the parameter `in_reply_to_status_id` in your `tweet status`. See the updates to your code below and it should now preserve the conversation:

```
function tweetEvent(eventMsg) {
    var replyto = eventMsg.in_reply_to_screen_name;
    var text = eventMsg.text;
    var from = eventMsg.user.screen_name;
    // the status update or tweet ID in which we will reply
    var nameID  = eventMsg.id_str;


    console.log(replyto + ' ' + from);

    if( (text.indexOf('myhandle') >= 0) || (from != 'myhandle')) {
        var reply = replies[Math.floor(Math.random() * replies.length)];
        var newtweet = '@' + from + ' ' + reply;
        tweetIt(newtweet);
    }

    function tweetIt(txt) {

        var tweet = {
          status: txt,
          in_reply_to_status_id: nameID
        }
}

    T.post('statuses/update', tweet, tweeted);

    function tweeted(err, data, response) {
      if (err) {
        console.log("Something went wrong!");
      } else {
        console.log("It worked!");
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this, it unfortunately failed to work because the variable defined is outside the function using it. I'm not sure where to place it otherwise

Comment: I moved the `tweetIt` function to `tweetEvent` and it worked. Thank you

Comment: Whoops! I was in a hurry. I will edit to reflect the change. Glad It worked!